# Videos not recording with videojs-record on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, video, html5-video, video-recording

Video recording not working on chrome/firefox on iPad

Steps to reproduce

Open below link and try to record video on iPad and it wont let me record the video
https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-record/examples/audio-video.html

browsers : Latest firefox and chrome
OSes : iOs 9.3.2

Issue created on github for the same : https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/issues/82

Comment: I used videojs-record plugin for recording.

Comment: Are you using code from below source :  https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record

Comment: Yes you are correct @Shekkar